# Como transpor de "largo" para "comprido" (wide para long) com diversas variáveis?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Tenho um dataframe com múltiplas variáveis, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, 
                 text="
ID  COR TIPO    SITUACAO_2016   SITUACAO_2017   SITUACAO_2018   SITUACAO_2019   SITUACAO_2020   ID_EMPRESA_2016 ID_EMPRESA_2017 ID_EMPRESA_2018 ID_EMPRESA_2019 ID_EMPRESA_2020
578 23  S   45  63  30  51  49  989 989 455 455 455
982 45  G   13  29  22  37  33  179 225 225 613 225
")
```

Algumas dessas variáveis tem o sufixo do ano, pois mudam com o tempo (`situacao` e `id_empresa`). Outras são fixas, não mudam com o tempo para um mesmo `id` (`cor` e `tipo`).

Como faço para transpor as variáveis para o formato longo, criando uma nova variável relativa ao ano da `situacao` e do `id_empresa`?

Resultado esperado:

```
output <-  read.table(header=TRUE, 
                     text="
ID  ANO COR TIPO    SITUACAO    ID_EMPRESA
578 2016    23  S   45  989
578 2017    23  S   63  989
578 2018    23  S   30  455
578 2019    23  S   51  455
578 2020    23  S   49  455
982 2016    45  G   13  179
982 2017    45  G   29  225
982 2018    45  G   22  225
982 2019    45  G   37  613
982 2020    45  G   33  225
")
```

De preferência, gostaria de uma solução o `tidyverse`, pois estou aprendendo a usá-lo e tenho alguma familiaridade.

O que fiz:

```
library(tidyverse)
output <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(., cols = situacao_2016:id_empresa_2020)
```

O que obtive:

```
dput(output)

structure(list(ID = c(578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 
578L, 578L, 578L, 982L, 982L, 982L, 982L, 982L, 982L, 982L, 982L, 
982L, 982L), COR = c(23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L), 
    TIPO = c("S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
    "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G"), name = c("SITUACAO_2016", 
    "SITUACAO_2017", "SITUACAO_2018", "SITUACAO_2019", "SITUACAO_2020", 
    "ID_EMPRESA_2016", "ID_EMPRESA_2017", "ID_EMPRESA_2018", 
    "ID_EMPRESA_2019", "ID_EMPRESA_2020", "SITUACAO_2016", "SITUACAO_2017", 
    "SITUACAO_2018", "SITUACAO_2019", "SITUACAO_2020", "ID_EMPRESA_2016", 
    "ID_EMPRESA_2017", "ID_EMPRESA_2018", "ID_EMPRESA_2019", 
    "ID_EMPRESA_2020"), value = c(45L, 63L, 30L, 51L, 49L, 989L, 
    989L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 13L, 29L, 22L, 37L, 33L, 179L, 225L, 
    225L, 613L, 225L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Consegui transpor, mas os nomes das colunas não ficaram como eu desejava. Não foi criada uma variável do ano. Além disso fiquei duas linhas por sujeito e por ano, uma para situacao e outra para `id_empresa`. Gostaria de obter o resultado como mencionado acima.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse pivot é um caso específico em que você tem uma duas variáveis no nome da coluna. A função `pivot_longer` tem como trabalhar com isso mas foi uma implementação relativamente recente. O último exemplo aqui https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html cobre um caso parecido.

Basicamente antes de pivotar ele separa as variáveis de acordo com o padrão fornecido em `names_pattern`. E em `names_to` eu sinalizo que a primeira parte do padrão são os nomes das colunas usando o `.value` e que a segunda parte vai para uma coluna ANO.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(header=TRUE, 
                 text="
ID  COR TIPO    SITUACAO_2016   SITUACAO_2017   SITUACAO_2018   SITUACAO_2019   SITUACAO_2020   ID_EMPRESA_2016 ID_EMPRESA_2017 ID_EMPRESA_2018 ID_EMPRESA_2019 ID_EMPRESA_2020
578 23  S   45  63  30  51  49  989 989 455 455 455
982 45  G   13  29  22  37  33  179 225 225 613 225
") 


df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with(c("SITUACAO", "ID_EMPRESA")),
               names_to = c(".value", "ANO"),
               names_pattern = "(.*)_(\\d*)") %>% 
  select(ID, ANO, everything())
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>       ID ANO     COR TIPO  SITUACAO ID_EMPRESA
#>    <int> <chr> <int> <chr>    <int>      <int>
#>  1   578 2016     23 S           45        989
#>  2   578 2017     23 S           63        989
#>  3   578 2018     23 S           30        455
#>  4   578 2019     23 S           51        455
#>  5   578 2020     23 S           49        455
#>  6   982 2016     45 G           13        179
#>  7   982 2017     45 G           29        225
#>  8   982 2018     45 G           22        225
#>  9   982 2019     45 G           37        613
#> 10   982 2020     45 G           33        225
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigada @Jorge! Òtima resposta!